# Implement searchview in toolbar in android

Tags: android

Hi i want to implement search functionality in my app over toolbar.Currently i have added SearchView element in activity_main.xml , but I don't know how to implement remaining logic. Please guide me to solve this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#99CC33"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="@string/app_name">
       <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/mySearchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:queryHint="Search by name"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

my AndroidManifest.xml is

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/splash_img"
    android:label="Call Logger"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.comforters.callLogger.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.comforters.callLogger.MainActivity"
        android:label="Call Logger" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".PhonecallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: what logic you want? Have you tried google? No one is going to write a logic for you here.

Comment: Thanks Ritesh, i dont want full code, i need just step by step information what i need to do

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu item inside your menu folder say /main/res/menu have the following

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</item>
```

That menu should be bound to the activity that will handle the search. In your Activity have something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(context.getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
}
```

Then in your adapter implement you filter logic, this will  depend on what you are searching and also on how the data is presented

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks Jaymo, I will try and let you know

Comment: If you found it useful you can upvote my answer. Thanks